# API Returns Dictionaries of Data. However, Can't Save Paginated Results in a Single Dictinoary?

Tags: python, api

I'm grabbing data from an API using the Python "requests" package. The API returns the data in json format, which I believe Python sees as a dictionary. I'm using the API's offset parameter to pull different results, hence the `for offset in range(0, 300, 100):` code in the example, below.

I should be getting 300 results and saving them as a dictionary to `X`. Then, I'm trying to use `dict.update(x)` to append/update `dict` so that I get a dictionary with all 300 results. However, I keep ending up with a dict with only 100 results. I think something is wrong with my use of `.update`.

```
dict = {} #Initialize dict as an empty dictionary

for offset in range(0, 300, 100):
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params={'offset':str(offset)})
x = r.json()
dict.update(x)
```

Any advice on what I'm doing wrong or better approaches?

Comment: Well it looks like the *keys* are clashing, in which case the values are *replaced*. So if you each time obtain a `{0: 'foo', 1: 'bar'}`, you indeed end up with the same dictionary.

Comment: I thought the same thing. Is there something like `append` for dictionaries?

Comment: but you *are* updating the dictionary, the problem is that *likely* the keys are the same. In a dictionary, a key occurs at most *once*, hence it "overwrites" the value.

Comment: Gotcha. The keys are the same. I understand why .update is causing issues now. Any suggestions on how to work around this when paginating results from an API?

Answer (score 1):

write your own dictionary update like so:

```
new_dict = {}
def own_update(dict):
    for key,val in dict.iteritems():
        if key in new_dict:
           new_dict[key] = new_dict[key].append(val)
        else:
           new_dict[key] = [value]
```

the `new_dict` will be updated as you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `defaultdict`

```
In [1]: from collections import defaultdict                                                                                                                                                                                                   

In [2]: results = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 2, 'b': 4, 'c': 5}]                                                                                                                                                                                

In [3]: d=defaultdict(list)                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

In [4]: for result in results: 
   ...:     for k, v in result.items(): 
   ...:         d[k].append(v)                                                                                                                                                                                                                

In [5]: print(d)                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'a': [1, 2], 'b': [2, 4], 'c': [5]})
```